# I'm having trouble defining a variable to JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, tradingview-api

The code works properly this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js" async>
          {
            "symbol": "BIST:ADEL",
            "width": "100%",
            "locale": "tr",
            "colorTheme": "dark",
            "isTransparent": false
          }
        </script>
```

But I have to use variables and it doesn't work that way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js" async>
          {
            "symbol": "BIST:" + localStorage.getItem('code'),
            "width": "100%",
            "locale": "tr",
            "colorTheme": "dark",
            "isTransparent": false
          }
        </script>
```

Error:
embed-widget-symbol-info.js:5 Widget settings parse error: SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 32 (line 2 column 31)
Invalid settings provided, fall back to defaults

What should i do?

I checked whether localStorage.getItem('code') variable is defined. Absolutely defined. I need to properly print the name in the variable into JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js" async>
          {
            "symbol": "BIST:" + localStorage.getItem('code'),
```

The problem with this is - you **are not** in a JavaScript context there, with that last line.

The content between the `<script>...</script>` tags only gets interpreted as JavaScript, if the script element does *not* have a `src` set. As soon as it does, everything between the tags gets ignored.
The script that was loaded via the `src` attribute can then go and find the `script` element in the DOM, and extract the content, *as text*. And what it then does with that text, is up to the script.

The script here apparently expects something it can directly parse as JSON - but you now fed it something, that simply isn't valid JSON.

I'm going to borrow from the other answer here, adding the necessary part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var widgetSettings = {
        "symbol": "BIST:" + localStorage.getItem('code'),
        "width": "100%",
        "locale": "tr",
        "colorTheme": "dark",
        "isTransparent": false
    };
    
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.async = true;
    // encode the widgetSettings as JSON, and set as text content of the script element:
    script.text = JSON.stringify(widgetSettings); 
    script.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-symbol-info.js';

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```